# Rails: Many-to-many Polymorphic Associations: Getting specific Type of Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have the following classes:

```
 class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :geographical_relations, :as => :contained
   has_many :geographical_units, :as => :container, :class_name => "GeographicalRelation"
 end

 class GeographicalRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :container, :polymorphic => true
   belongs_to :contained, :polymorphic => true
 end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :geographical_relations, :as => :contained
end
```

And I want to be able to, from a Country record, get all the Regions in which it is contained:

```
c = Country.find(1)
c.regions #=> should return all the regions in which c is contained
```

For now I've created the following method:

```
def regions
  self.geographical_relations.where(:container_type => "Region").map{|relation| relation.container}
end
```

But I wonder if there's any way to set an "has_many" association to do this for me.

Cheers.

**EDIT:**

after trying the alternatives suggested in the comments I only got nice ActiveRecord errors.

The has_many_polymorphs gem seems to be a good way to do this, but for Rails 3 it is not 'officially' supported so for my case it is not a good option.

So I will work with methods like the one described above, putting them in modules and including the respective modules inside each "container"/"contained" models. This seems to work ok. =) Only change I made, to avoid N+1 Queries was adding 'includes':

```
def regions
  self.geographical_relations.includes(:container).where(:container_type => "Region").map{|relation| relation.container}
end
```

Hopefully this works nicely and fast... =P =)

Anyway if anyone has an answer to solve this I'll look forward to see it! =)

Thanks all!

Comment: A `has_many :regions, :through => :geographical_relations, :class_name => 'Region'` doesn't work?

Comment: No, that gives me the following: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :region or :regions in model GeographicalRelation.  Try 'has_many :regions, :through => :geographical_relations, :source => <name>'.  Is it one of :container or :contained?

Comment: I'm assuming you followed that suggestion and it didn't work, right? `has_many :regions, :through => :geographical_relations, :source => :contained`

Comment: I tried before with :source => :container. And now I tried with :source => :contained. Both give me something like this: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Country#regions' on the polymorphic object 'Contained#contained'.

Comment: I think maybe what you're looking for is the behaviour provided by `has_many_polymorphs`, but be careful - seems to me that it's no longer maintained, but it appears that there are some forks to make it work with rails 3: http://jystewart.net/process/2010/05/has_many_polymorphs-and-rails-3/